# Fabfile path problem on windows

Tags: windows, mercurial, path, fabric

I'm trying to deploy my site using Fabric and Mercurial. In the Windows command line, running `hg push` works perfectly with no problems.

But when I try writing

```
local("hg push")
```

in a fabfile and running it, I get the error:

```
'"hg push"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Googling gave me an idea that it might be a problem with the `PATH` variable in Python subprocesses, for example here: [Why would an "command not recognized" error occur only when a window is populated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283431/why-would-an-command-not-recognized-error-occur-only-when-a-window-is-populated).

Can you help me out? Is the bug in Fabric or in my own code?

Thanks.

Comment: Fabric is not well-supported on Windows at this time, so I'm not surprised to see this happening.

If you please include some extra detail, it might be possible to do better; add debug logging using "with show('everything', 'debug'):" and include the contents of your PATH.

Additionally, include all 'env' settings you've got at the time.

Comment: Chris R: I am still not sure what the problem was. Putting everything inside `show('everything','debug')` did not reveal any more information about the problem. I tried setting `env.path` directly and got weird results as mentioned below. Changing local() to `os.system()` fixed the problem, especially for a simple command like `hg push`.

Answer (score 1):

As Chris R mentions, we don't do a ton of Windows support as none of the core devs are Windows users; we have to rely on reports and suggestions from our more savvy Windows users.

It sounds like this could be related to [this recently fixed, but not released, bug](http://code.fabfile.org/issues/show/258) -- it will be in Fabric 1.0.2 which should be out soon. If you're feeling brave, you can test it out now via:

```
pip install -e git+git://github.com/bitprophet/fabric@1.0#egg=Fabric
```

If you then do `fab -V`, it should say it's 1.0.2a -- if so, running your fabfile may work better. Please let us know if you do this!

Comment: Changing local() to `os.system()` fixed the problem, especially for a simple command like `hg push`. Please let me know if you would like me to file a bug report.

Comment: Updating to 1.0.2a as described above worked for me. With Fabric 1.0.1 "local('echo %PATH%')" on windows failed with the error message about incorrect filename. With Fabric 1.0.2a the same command worked as expected.

Comment: I'm on 2.4.0 and I'm still getting this error. Also, I'm having trouble with SSH keys not playing well with Fabric but are working fine from terminal. The error has to do with underlying SSH client not being able to recognize the keys.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the you need to add Mercurial to the Fabric process's `PATH`.

Maybe something like:

```
fabric.context_managers.path(<path to your hg.exe>)
run('hg push')
```

See the docs for the [path context manager](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.0.1/api/core/context_managers.html#fabric.context_managers.path).  It wasn't clear if `path` applies to `local` commands, but `run` commands are explicitly referenced.

Comment: Hey, I tried that but it wasn't appending to `env.path`. So then I tried setting env.path directly. The output was `local: PATH=$PATH:"C:\Program Files\Mercurial\hg.exe" hg push` The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score -2):

Neither of the fixes provided worked, but changing

`local("hg push")`

to

```
os.system("hg push")
```

solved the problem.

Comment: As someone new to Fabric, It would be good to know why this has been down-voted with no comments ? whats wrong with the use of os.system here ?

Comment: @jowansebastian Because it's a bad practice to use the `system `. Plus it's outside Fabric's control. Anyway, this sucks for Windows devs becaue it still doesn't work on 2.4.0